# Building a raised platform fort

Tags: floor, joists

I want to build a 4m x 5m raised platform for my kids fort.  It will be 2m high.  I have a few questions:

It is OK to attach the posts at the corners or will I need more in the middle?

What do I attach the frame to the posts with?

How far apart should I place the floor joists?

What do I attach the floor joists with?

With the floor boards do I need some space between them?

Thank you.  I probably will have more questions.

Comment: You're basically building a free standing deck.  You have to follow all the rules for framing a deck - sizing joists, beams, posts, etc. etc.  However you don't have a nice sturdy house to attach to - with it freestanding, the risk of collapse is far greater.  Be super careful - deck collapses kill or injure more people than any other construction error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grab a framing manual from your hardware supplier, it will tell you what size beams and posts are required to make a sturdy floor.

> It is OK to attach the posts at the corners or will I need more in the middle?

4 posts sounds workable. but yo will probably need bracing to keep the posts straight.
or else use very deep holes for the posts.

> What do I attach the frame to the posts with?

Bolts of a weather resistant type eg: galvanized.

> How far apart should I place the floor joists?

See framing manual.

> What do I attach the floor joists with?

Nails or joist hangers. Depending whether you want to pass the joist over the frame or butt them up-to it.

> With the floor boards do I need some space between them?

Does it rain where you live?  Basically you are building a deck. The gaps allow rain to drain through the deck.

Comment: A 4m x 5m (13.12 ft x 16.4 ft) deck will need more than just 4 posts at the corners. +